# Would it be bad to ask questions for program name ideas?

Tags: discussion, questions

Would it be acceptable if I asked questions about ideas on what to name a program? I can't think of a name for a program and I thought it would be closed so I just want to make sure if its acceptable before I do so.

Comment: it would be considered as *too localized*, I guess, and even if not, it will not help a lot to future visitors, so I think it is bad idea

Comment: For future reference, I might point out that you can generally "go with your gut" with regard to the types of questions that it would be acceptable to ask. You even indicate here that you suspect such a question would be promptly closed. More often than not, the community is correct in its discrimination of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very clear violation of the FAQ; in particular, the guidelines laid out in the section concerning the types of questions which one should *not* ask.

As such, almost any of the available close reasons would be applicable. As [om-nom-nom points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128875/would-it-be-bad-to-ask-questions-for-program-name-ideas/128880#comment351995_128875), such a question would be "too localized." Personally, I'd choose the "not constructive" option. If one were feeling charitable, she could opt for simply "off topic".

No, [you'll have to get a [popular] blog in order to properly outsource all of your project naming needs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html).